# Backgroundworker is always busy

Tags: c#, event-handling, backgroundworker

I'm new to using event handlers and backgroundworkers, so I may be missing something completely obvious here. Still, I've been trying to fix this for two days, so I thought I might as well see what anyone had to say.

I have a backgroundworker called SqlExpressDownloader. It starts running at the beginning of my program, the rest of the work runs, and then it should wait for the operations in the `SqlExpressDownloader_DoWork()` method to complete before continuing. The only problem is that for some reason whenever I do `while(SqlExpressDownloader.IsBusy)`, it always responds as busy and therefore will wait forever.

The code for the event handler is here:

```
    private void SqlExpressDownloader_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {
        string sSource = string.Format("{0}\\{1}", Paths.Settings_Common, "sqlexpr_x64_enu.exe");
        Debug.WriteLine(sSource);
        Debug.WriteLine("http://www.elexioamp.com/Install/redistributables/sql2008r2express/sqlexpr_x64_enu.exe");
        if (!System.IO.File.Exists(sSource))
        {
            WebClient oWebClient = new WebClient();
            oWebClient.DownloadProgressChanged += DownloadProgressChanged;
            oWebClient.DownloadDataCompleted += DownloadComplete;

            oWebClient.DownloadFileAsync(new System.Uri("http://www.elexioamp.com/Install/redistributables/sql2008r2express/sqlexpr_x64_enu.exe"), sSource);

            while (oWebClient.IsBusy)
            {
                Thread.Sleep(100);
            }

            e.Result = "";
            DownloadFinished = true;
        }
    }
```

I have watched the code and have watched it complete this method. I even added a `return` after the `DownloadFinished = true`, but it still responds as busy. What I want to know is how to make the backgroundworker respond as not busy.

EDIT
The events are all added in the constructor as shown here:

```
        SqlExpressDownloader = new BackgroundWorker();
        SqlExpressDownloader.DoWork += new DoWorkEventHandler(this.SqlExpressDownloader_DoWork);
        SqlExpressDownloader.RunWorkerCompleted += new RunWorkerCompletedEventHandler(this.SqlExpressDownloader_RunWorkerCompleted);
```

The `RunWorkerCompleteEventHandler` looks like this:

```
    private void SqlExpressDownloader_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Error != null)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine("The actions are complete.");
        }
        else
        {
            Debug.WriteLine("Error in completed work.");
        }
    }
```

But, when I debugged it last, it didn't actually trigger.

Comment: How are you starting the worker?

Comment: In the main method, I'm starting it with `SqlExpressDownloader.RunWorkerAsync()`.

Comment: Are you using a while loop similar to the one in the body of the method when checking the IsBusy of the worker? Does the RunWorkerCompleted event trigger when the method is complete?

Comment: The while loop looks almost exactly like the one listed here. I updated information about the RunWorkerCompleted in the question.

Comment: Is there some other code that adds a handler to the DoWork event, perhaps in the .designer.cs file? Your code should work the way you have it.

Comment: I can't find any, I've been looking. I know that this DoWork event is working because I've been debugging it. I don't know why it won't trigger the Runworker_completed method, something must be wrong there.

Comment: This question is answered here:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14430979/why-backgroundworker-always-is-busy?rq=1

The problem is that the completed event is run in the main thread - you can't just sit there and wait for isBusy to go false.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can replace your code with more elegant async/await solution like this

```
private async Task SqlExpressDownloadAsync()
{
    string sSource = string.Format("{0}\\{1}", Paths.Settings_Common, "sqlexpr_x64_enu.exe");
    Debug.WriteLine(sSource);
    Debug.WriteLine("http://www.elexioamp.com/Install/redistributables/sql2008r2express/sqlexpr_x64_enu.exe");
    if (!System.IO.File.Exists(sSource))
    {
        WebClient oWebClient = new WebClient();
        oWebClient.DownloadProgressChanged += DownloadProgressChanged;
        oWebClient.DownloadDataCompleted += DownloadComplete;
        await oWebClient.DownloadFileTaskAsync(new System.Uri("http://www.elexioamp.com/Install/redistributables/sql2008r2express/sqlexpr_x64_enu.exe"), sSource);  
    }   
}
```

Comment: I'm not familiar with tasks. Am I able to track the progress of the download like I am using event handlers on the backgroundworker? There's a GUI component involved in my project. I'll try this out.

Comment: This is not running async at the moment though. You should wrap it in a task.run

Comment: Absolutely! I added missing event handles, they will will fire as with your code.

Comment: @Patrick could you elaborate? The code awaits for DownloadFileTaskAsync

Comment: @Patrick good question, how long do you think it will run? Please provide your answer as well.

Comment: What's that suppose to mean?

Comment: If File.Exist is checking a file at a UNC path for instance it could take, I dunno, a few seconds. What is your limit for running async? Is it a general number of lines under 8 that you don't find should take "too long"?

Comment: If Paths.Settings_Common is a property that loads something from a database that can take some time as well. The fact is you don't know how long it will take since you can't be certain how things are implemented.

Comment: @Patrick you are correct, I would either move the whole code to Task.Run or remove the check for file existence if really not needed here. I don't think that checking for file existence is a good way to tell that exact same version of file has been previously  downloaded.

Answer (score 3):

Instead of querying `SqlExpressDownloader.IsBusy` in a loop, try subscribing to the `RunWorkerCompleted` event of the `BackgroundWorker` and place your code in there that should only occur after the `DoWork` event has completed.

You'll also have access to the `RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs`, which you can check to make sure no error was thrown from the `DoWork` portion of your `BackgroundWorker`.

```
    ...
    ...
    SqlExpressDownloader.RunWorkerCompleted += SqlExpressDownloader_RunWorkerCompleted;
    SqlExpressDownloader.RunWorkerAsync();
}

private void SqlExpressDownloader_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Error != null)
    {
        // do something in response to the error
    }

    // stuff to do after DoWork has completed
}
```

I found [Joe Albahari's tutorial](http://www.albahari.com/threading/part3.aspx#_BackgroundWorker) helpful when I was learning how to use these.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue.  DownloadASync would fire but .IsBusy would always stay on true.

This probably won't be a common problem, just thought I share my resolution.

I used

```
MessageBox.Show(new Form() { TopMost = true }, "", "")
```

This was the cause.  I also tried:

```
var t = new Form() { TopMost = true };
MessageBox.Show(t, "", "");
t.Dispose();
```

This caused the same issue.

My code had multiple threads, I assume one of them must have gotten stuck, or perhaps the MessageBox(the new Form() { TopMost = true; } ) call created a stuck thread.

As soon as I removed that part, eg.

```
MessageBox.Show("", "");
```

Everything worked as expected again.

So maybe you are creating another thread somewhere that is causing your issue.